# JS revision for jQuery 1.7+

Tags: jquery

So I have a code that looks something like this

```
$(".something").live({
   mouseover:function(e){
     //do stuff
   },
   mouseout:function(e){
     //do or undo other stuff
   }
});
```

But since this `.live` method is deprecated in jQuery1.7+, I have to do a bit of revising. 
To start with, it should look like:

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".something",function(e){
  //do stuff here
});
```

How about the `mouseout` thingy? Any quick way to merge the two or will I be forced to make separate coding for them?
Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind you don't _HAVE_ to change it yet. They are not removing anything at this point.

Comment: I have to ask this question because something went wrong when I upgraded to 1.7+ But of course, this is what I thought the reason was. Can't go down to the minutest details to thoroughly check. But with the answers I got, problem fixed. Thanks for this warning (the svn repository should come in handy in case). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave the map:

```
$(document).on(
    {
         mouseover : function(){ ... }
        , mouseout : function(){ ... }
    }
    , '.something'
);
```

Comment: I'd appreciate a removal of the downvote as my answer **is** correct.

Comment: I'm not the one that down-voted you.  I just commented when it was __not__ correct :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on({
   mouseover:function(e){
     //do stuff
   },
   mouseout:function(e){
     //do or undo other stuff
   }
}, ".something");
```

Based on:

> .on( events-map [, selector] [, data] )

[From the doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-map-selector-data)

Comment: .live is deprecated in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov sorry i accidentally typed that. fixed ^_^

Comment: @cwolves sorry i accidentally typed `live`